# How can I insert the Event Date in this scenario?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Example Workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6_DHjQZF44TempvRW5PXzZ4eXM/view?usp=sharing)

If the "Owner ID" matches on the "Master" and "Lookup" sheets. How can I have the "Event" cell filled on the Master Sheet with the corresponding "Event Name" from the "Lookup" sheet that has a date +/- 2 days from the "Submit Date" on the "Master" Sheet?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Screenshots (included above): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bpf7.jpg

Comment: Please provide the relevant details of your spreadsheet in your question instead of the linked file.  Some folks (me included) don't want to open Excel files off the internet.  Also, this Q&A site serves as a better archive of information if it is not dependent on a file remaining on an external server.  If you want to add a screenshot, please include a link to it in the question or comment and someone (possibly me) will edit it in.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've attached screenshots for you. http://imgur.com/a/grKYG  I'll add this to my original post as well.

Comment: What if more than one event matched the criteria (same owner Id and date with +-2 days) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:  =INDEX(Lookup!$B$2:$B$21,MATCH(1,INDEX((Lookup!$A$2:$A$21=Master!A2)*(Lookup!$C$2:$C$21<=Master!B2+2)*(Lookup!$C$2:$C$21>=Master!B2-2),0),0))